# Validar que una función de jquery no venga vacía

Tags: jquery

Tengo un pequeño buscador rápido en jquery, Quisiera comprobar cuando viene vació `return ValorBusquedaDos.test($(this).text())` he tratado de sacar un `console.log()` o un `alert()` pero no me funciona.

El buscador hace su trabajo correctamente solo quisiera agregar un mensaje o algo cuando venga vació.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    (function($) {
        $('#sectorBuscarDos').keyup(function () {
        var ValorBusquedaDos = new RegExp($(this).val(), 'i');
        $('.BusquedaRapidaDos .card').hide();
         $('.BusquedaRapidaDos .card').filter(function () {
            return ValorBusquedaDos.test($(this).text());
        }).show();
         $('#sectorBuscarDos').val('')
    })
    }(jQuery));
});




<input type="text" id="sectorBuscarDos"/>
<div class="BusquedaRapidaDos">
<div class="card">1</div>
<div class="card">2</div>
<div class="card">3</div>
<div class="card">4</div>
<div class="card">5</div>
<div class="card">6</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hola Daniel. No veo en tu código donde intentas mandar mensaje si compruebas qie viene vacio. ¿Puedes pulsar en [edit] para añadir lo que has intentado y los errores o problemas concretos que has tenido ?  MIra [ask] y [mcve] para más info. Un saludo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para efectuar esto, has de guardar el resultado de filter en una variable ("cards") y comprobar el tamaño del array retornado. Sería de la siguiente manera:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    (function($) {
        $('#sectorBuscarDos').keyup(function () {
        var ValorBusquedaDos = new RegExp($(this).val(), 'i');
        $('.BusquedaRapidaDos .card').hide();
         var cards = $('.BusquedaRapidaDos .card').filter(function () {
            var filters = ValorBusquedaDos.test($(this).text());
            return filters;
        });
        if(cards.length === 0) console.log('void');
        cards.show();
     $('#sectorBuscarDos').val('')
    })
    }(jQuery));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="sectorBuscarDos"/>
<div class="BusquedaRapidaDos">
<div class="card">1</div>
<div class="card">2</div>
<div class="card">3</div>
<div class="card">4</div>
<div class="card">5</div>
<div class="card">6</div>
</div>
```